# Render a function inside a component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My target is to create a breadcrumb component in react js.
I used Ant Design in my App, but I have some issues with a parth of it.

In the documentation of Ant Design i found a solution for creating dynamic breadcrumbs, but can't find out how to apply the code.

Using, Ant design i built the next app:

```js
    import React from "react";
    import {Link, BrowserRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";
    import {Breadcrumb} from 'antd';

    //from here starts the code from Ant Design Documentation
    const routes = [
        {
            path: 'index',
            breadcrumbName: 'home',
        },
        {
            path: 'first',
            breadcrumbName: 'first',
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/general',
                    breadcrumbName: 'General',
                },
                {
                    path: '/layout',
                    breadcrumbName: 'Layout',
                },
                {
                    path: '/navigation',
                    breadcrumbName: 'Navigation',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            path: 'second',
            breadcrumbName: 'second',
        },
    ];

    function itemRender(route, params, routes, paths) {
        const last = routes.indexOf(route) === routes.length - 1;
        return last ? (
            <span>{route.breadcrumbName}</span>
        ) : (
            <Link to={paths.join('/')}>{route.breadcrumbName}</Link>
        );
    }
return <Breadcrumb itemRender={itemRender} routes={routes} />;
    //here is the end of the code from Ant Design

    function App() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>here i want to render my breadcrumb</p>
            </div>
        );
    }

    export default App;
```

Also, the return statement is located outside of the function and i get error due of this.

How to create, using this implementation, a breadcrumb, and how to render `itemRender` function inside my component, and from where should i get these params `itemRender(route, params, routes, paths)`?

Comment: Can you take a look at your code? You have a return statement sitting outside of a function; this isn't valid. -- Ah, I see you've addressed this in your question. Yeah, you may only return from within a function.

Comment: @ndugger, i know, but in this way is written in documentation and i can't understand why

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Breadcrum` component in App body

```
function App() {
  return (
      <div>
        <Breadcrumb itemRender={itemRender} routes={routes} />
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you was right. I changed my code , but the routes don't change.  Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-flower-g3iye  Could you take a look, please? Regarding downvote, i don't see downvotes

Comment: @Asking Since you don't have the react-router configured in your app

Comment: do you mea that i should create pages and after that to  use `<Route path="/page">`. Could you show, please in my example?

Comment: from where they take the parameter `route` from `function itemRender(route, params, routes, paths) {` ?

Comment: @Mwirabua Tim, could you help me to solve my issue with ant design?